# Add objects to list in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, list, webmethod

I've been trying to create a simple web application that registers users and saves their details using a list. Problem is that after adding the user successfully in the first call to the RegisterUser function, the list is empty again in the second call. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the function is an HTTP method?

code:

```
public class WS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void registerUser()
    {
        try
        {
            string s = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[0].ToString();
            User tempUser = new User();
            tempUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(s);
            users.Add(tempUser);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to keep users in session then retrive from there before add another item again.

Comment: `List<>` is not a linked list.  It is an array list.

Comment: @Mert: what do you mean? save the new User in session state and then when retrieve him?

Comment: don't you trying to fill users with data comes from Http calls? you can't do that, every call resets users. you need to keep users in somewhere memory or database ect.

Comment: you need to save users somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void registerUser()
    {
        try
        {
            if(Session["users"] == null)
                Session["users"] = new List<User>();

            List<User> users = (List<User>)Session["users"];

            string s = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[0].ToString();
            User tempUser = new User();
            tempUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(s);
            users.Add(tempUser);

            Session["users"] = users;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Web is stateless, so if you are not storing your list somewhere capable of maintaining state (database, session, xml file etc.) on every load your list will be reinitialized. The answer above shows you one of the possible solutions.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this decoration needs to be applied to the WebMethod attribute in order to use session state https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, I have tried this but I still have a problem: I save the list (Session["users"] = users;) but them when I try to get the list back it returns null (var s = Session["users"]). How do I retrieve the list from the sessions??
Update - So I've read that I'm supposed to use Cache instead...

Comment: I believe you should use database, no way to know without knowing actually what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

The `users` field will be instantiated every time a new instance of the `WS` class is created. To persist the data across calls you need to make it [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/98f28cdx.aspx). However, you will lose the data every time the web server service restarts so you should probably look at persisting to a database or other persistent data store instead.

Code:

```
private static List<User> users = new List<User>(); // could probably be readonly too
```

If this is intended to be a security solution and not just a data gathering exercise I would further suggest a rethink of what you are doing. .NET has a membership provider subsystem available which you should look into.

Comment: First thing, thank you very much for your explanation; second - so a new instance of the webservice is created whenever I call one of the web methods?

Comment: Yes that's right. Web handlers have an IsReusable property but I'm not sure that's available to web services.